# how to send "if" statement in helm array template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I would like to have a `if exists` check in my array object of the helm template. My YAML looks like this:

```
servers:
- hosts: dev
  port: 443
{{- if .Values.stage.enabled -}}
- hosts: stage
  port: 443
{{- end -}}
```

I received  `error converting YAML to JSON: yaml:  mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Is nesting `if` condition not allowed in helm template? If so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The `-` inside the curly braces causes the Go `text/template` engine to swallow the whitespace adjacent to it.  If you run `helm template` on this (highly recommended) you will see output like

```yaml
servers:
- hosts: dev
  port: 443- hosts: stage
  port: 443and then whatever comes next in the template
```

If you put conditionals on lines of their own like this, as a rule of thumb, it often works well to include the `-` at the start of the line (to remove the newline before it) but not at the end of the line (preserving the indentation on the next line).

```yaml
servers:
- hosts: dev
  port: 443
{{- if .Values.stage.enabled }}{{/* <-- no `-` here */}}
- hosts: stage
  port: 443
{{- end }}{{/* <-- no `-` here either */}}
```